# Is there any Flutter SDK version which is optional to use null safe?

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

I'm trying to update a big project with the version below, to a version with null safe but minimizing file changes.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"
```

I've following dart's doc https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide#step1-wait but I'm not certain that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

May the [Release Notes](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes) will help you.

At least I saw in every release some null safety update at least since 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

the null safety was introduced in the 2.12.0 version so any version under 2.12.0 the null safety is optional, but if you are having troubles with the null safety you can avoid al the "request" keyword using a ? when you declare the variables like this.

required String name;

to

String ? name;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).